# $2n$ objects each of $3$ kinds are given to $2$ persons so that each get $3n$ objects

Tags: permutations, combinations

Here i have a question which i am not getting.

$2n$ objects each of $3$ kinds are given to $2$ persons so that each get $3n$ objects.Prove that this can be done in $3n^2 + 2n +1$ ways.

Here what i am not able to understand is it is not valid for all the values of n. Isn't it? So how we can proceed?

Comment: I think what they mean is $6n$ objects in total. $2n$ of each kind.

Comment: yes may be. i am thinking the same..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first person's $3n$ objects can be distributed over the three kinds in $\binom{3n+2}2$ different ways. But then we need to subtract the $3\binom{3n+2-(2n+1)}2$ distributions in which one of the kinds has more than $2n$ objects. Thus the total is

$$
\binom{3n+2}2-3\binom{n+1}2=\frac{(3n+2)(3n+1)-3(n+1)n}2=3n^2+3n+1\;.
$$

Counting by hand for $n=1$ suggests that this result is correct and the one you cite isn't.